# error handling exercise + dealing with floating point numbers issues

Tags: python, error-handling, floating-point, integer

> context: In a exercise about error-handling(in python), I have been asked to use
> the 'try statement' and 'except clause' in order to ask the user for
> input of a decimal number, which then must be converted to a floating
> point value.
>
> -I must print my own error message if an error occurs (in this case "not an decimal value!").
> -I must also print the official python error message.
> -I have to include an else clause to then confirm that a valid decimal has been input.

I will include what I've been able to come up with so far below:

```
    error = False
    try:
        number = float(input("\nEnter an decimal value (e.g, 1.3): "))
    except ValueError as errorMsg:
        error = True
        print("\nNot an decimal.")
        print("\nPython exception:", errorMsg)
    else:
        print("you have entered a valid decimal")
```

This seems to work both when I enter an actual decimal value, and when I enter a non numerical value like an alphabetical character. I run into my problem where I have entered a normal integer (1,2,3 etc.), where it indicates that there is no error and that I have entered a decimal or floating point value.
I have tried multiple ways of coding this and have ended up with the same result and I am  now at a standstill, annoyingly it is probably a simple solution or an error on my behalf due to knowledge gaps, so I would appreciate if anybody has a solution or suggestion so I can fix this issue. Many thanks!

Comment: The function `float(x)` tries to convert the value of `x` to a float value. Since integers can be converted to floats (1 == 1.0), the program will not raise an exception.  
You can try to check if `number == int(number)`.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I understand now why it will not raise a Value Error, but I still for the life of me cant get it to work, I have tried checking if the number is an integer in several positions throughout the code block, but end up with the same result or with  both integer and decimal inputs returning the "not a decimal" message. This is definitely a problem on my end as I am pretty new to coding, but if u have any further insight to what I may be still getting wrong, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Let's say that the user enteted an integer, say 1. Now you have `number = 1` and you can check `if number == int(number)`. In this case you will get `True`. Now what will happen if the number is 1.2? In this case the above `if` sentence will be evaluated to `False`.